# How to change div from one position to another in html using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a html page. In that what I need is, the text to animate in one position and it has to go and fix in some other position. Here is my code

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="text">Sample Text</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var textFxSettings = {
            animation: 3,
            color: "#111",
            animationType: "in",
            speed: 1000
        };

        jQuery.cjTextFx(textFxSettings); // INIT FUNCTION
        jQuery.cjTextFx.animate("#text", {
            onComplete: myFunction
        });

    });
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#text{
position:absolute;
top:230px;
left:530px;
font-size:24px;
}

.text_pos{

animation:spin 3s;
-moz-animation:spin 3s; /* Firefox */
-webkit-animation:spin 3s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-animation:spin 3s; /* Opera */
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin{
    0%   {   -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0px); }
    100% {   -webkit-transform: translate(0px, -150px); }   
}
```

This translation is going to the correct position but after 1 cycle it come back to its original position(top:230). I want the text to be positioned at top:80. I tried by changing the position of text_pos class, but it is not working.
Can anyone help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can used to change position to div like

```
  $("#text").css({"top":"10px","left":"20px"});
```

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking. There will be no animation, and the OP is using a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

put the script whatever is there in $(document).ready(function()) in ajax.stop function like

```
 $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
  var textFxSettings = {
        animation: 3,
        color: "#111",
        animationType: "in",
        speed: 1000
    };

    jQuery.cjTextFx(textFxSettings); // INIT FUNCTION
    jQuery.cjTextFx.animate("#text", {
        onComplete: myFunction
    });
 }
```